# Pivot Tables in Crystal Reports?

Tags: crystal-reports, pivot-table

I need to make a pivot table on my Crystal Reports.  Right now i'm using an ODBC connection...but while I know you can create a pivot table in CR, I am not 100% sure how to do it. Anybody here know an easy step-by-step way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Within Crystal Reports go to File/New and choose Cross-Tab Report. Setting up the data connection and links are the same as a standard Crystal Report, and you simply add the fields that you require into the columns and rows boxes on the Cross-Tab set up screen. If you are familiar with Pivot tables/cross-tab reports then this should be fairly straightforward.