# Display Some Rows as Columns in Crystal Report

Tags: c#, crystal-reports, report

I would like to create a report that has the following Format:

```
ID-1    |Name           |Subject 1|Subject 2|Subject 3|Subject 4|
ID-2    |Father Name    |Marks 1  |Marks 2  |Marks 3  |Marks 4  |
```

The data that is returned in the dataset is of the format:

```
ID-1|ID-2|Name|FatherName|Subject 1|Marks 1|etc|Etc|
ID-1|ID-2|Name|FatherName|Subject 2|Marks 2|etc|Etc|
ID-1|ID-2|Name|FatherName|Subject 3|Marks 3|etc|Etc|
```

I tried using Crosstab but I wasn't able to acheive the required output. An hint on how to accomplish it ? AND/OR what Crystal Report Feature|Control will help me achieve it ?

In a more sumamrized way, What I would like to do is to Show the Marks of the Subjects that are returned as multiple rows in a single row and display the similar data in each tow i.e. the ID-1, ID-2, Name. Father Name etc. just once ! 
(Note: The Data needs to be shown in 2 lines per Student as shown in the example.

Comment: don't lear crystal report that is obsolete in vs2012. instead learn and use XtraReport rather

Comment: We already have some reports in Crystal Report and cannot turn to any other solution at this moment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By using [**pivot**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) you can easily convert rows to column. Check [this](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a5d11/1) pivot example on sqlfiddle for your problem.

Comment: Will like to know if it is possible to achieve in Crystal Reports.

Comment: Try this link on making Pivot Tables in Crystal: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1639666/pivot-tables-in-crystal-reports