# Is there any solution for unpivot with dynamic columns

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot

I have data like

Table1:

```
YEAR     PD         REAL_GDP     REAL_PRIVATE_CONSUMPTION        
2018    0.007509274 140712.6      78450.8
```

---

Table2:

```
description                     value
Debt_service_ratio_paid         0.06
Personal_disposable_income  0.000000005
Intercept                   2.0004
Real_GDP                    -0.004
Debt_service_ratio_paid         0.06
```

So basically some Columns of table one are rows in table2 . I want to multiply value of for ex. real GDP so output should be `140712.6*-0.004....`
I tried `unpivot`.. but the problem here is wanted to calculate this for those column only which are common in table 1 and table 2 .... and rows will be added in table two in future ... so I wanna know if there is any solution for dynamic `unpivot` where I can take common columns of both the table and those columns only I need to `unpivot` in first table.

Comment: "*I tried unpivot*" - Show us what you've tried, the whole query. Don't add it as comments, [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/56075590/edit) your question and paste it.. Also, have a look at answers such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45638536) for implementing dynamic unpivot